# Find $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ that maximizes $ (n+10)/(n^3+10)$

Tags: number-theory

$(n+10)/(n^3+10)=(n+10)/(n^3+1000-990)$

I have thought about something like this. But am not sure about how to proceed with this. So I would like some help.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The question should be : find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$ ?) such that $(n+10)/(n^3+10)$ is the biggest possible

Comment: Yes the question if find n

Answer (score 4):

You have that for $n=1$ that $11/11=1$ so you want to find $$\frac{n+10}{n^3+10}> 1$$
Otherwise the maximum value is $1$.

If $n^3+10>0$ we can multiply both sides of inequality to get
$$n+10> n^3+10\\n> n^3\\0> n(n-1)(n+1)$$
This happens when $n< -1$ or $0< n< 1$ The only integer satisfying $n^3+10>0$ and $n< -1$ is $-2$ and there are no integers satisfying $0<n<1$. For $n=-2$ we get $8/2=4$ so it's greater.

Now if $n^3+10<0$ then when we multiply we must also flip signs so
$$n+10<n^3+10\\n(n-1)(n+1)>0 $$
This happens when $-1<n<0$ or $n>1$ none of those satisfy $n^3+10<0$ hence for $n=-2$ is the maximum.

Comment: [+1] Nice derivation, very different from mine...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, it's quite useful to restrict the domain of the solution set when dealing with integers because you can brute force the solution. Though your solution is easier to generalize to non-integer cases.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(n)=\dfrac{n+10}{n^3+10}$.

After having asked my computer to produce a certain number of values of $f(n)$, I was convinced that

> The maximum value of $f(n)$ is $4$ and occurs for $n=-2$.

(and uniquely for this value).

Now, the proof. My idea has been to write $f(n)=4+g(n)$ and to attempt to establish that $g(n)<0$ in general with the exceptional case $g(-2)=0$.

$$g(n)=f(n)-4=\dfrac{-4n^3+n-30}{n^3+10}$$

$g(n)$ has a numerator that, rather naturaly, can be factorized with an $(n+2)$ factor (remember that $g(n)$ must be $0$ for $n=-2$), under the form :

$$-4n^3+n-30=(n+2)(-4n^2+8n-15)$$

Writing :

$$g(n)=\dfrac{n+2}{n^3+10}\underbrace{(-4n^2+8n-15)}_{h(n)}. \tag{1}$$

with

$h(n)=-4n^2+8n-15=-11-4(n-1)^2$ always $<0$,

our objective will be reached if (refer to (1)), we can prove that:

$$\forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z}, \ \ \ \dfrac{n+2}{n^3+10} \geq 0 \tag{2}$$

(2) is easy to establish : let us separate :

- case $n=-2$ for which we get $0$, (yielding the maximal case),
- cases where $n > -2$ (for which (2) is true as quotient of two positive numbers) and
- cases where $n<-2$ for which we can say :

$$n \leq -3 \ \implies  \ n+2\leq -1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ n^3+10\leq-17$$

thus, we obtain two negative numbers, yielding a positive quotient in (2).

Comment: I have attempted to improve the introduction of my answer in order to show that I had a rigorous direction of thought, that can be applied as well to any similar problem.